# How to find Component name using Angular DevTools?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I recently started developing in Angular from React. In React DevTools, you can select the pointer button in the console, click on a location on screen and it would bring up the name of the component. Is there something similar with Angular DevTools?

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://angular.io/guide/devtools. It's similar to the react version but with the Angular specific flavor.